# using locate function on calculated field in delphi

Tags: delphi, locate, tadotable

How can we use ***locate*** function or a same operation function using a calculated field in delphi Tadotable?
something like this

`SampleAdotable.locate('samplefield',text,[lopartialkey]);`

where samplefield is a calculated field in SampleAdotable.In normal case an exception with this message is created:

```
Item can not be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal
```

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `SampleField` is of type `fkCalculated`, I don't think you can use this field as a field whose value you try to locate in a call to `Locate`.

The reason is that `Locate` calls `TCustomADODataSet.LocateRecord` which generates the error you quote and the reason it does is that `SampleField` is not a field in the ADO `Recordset` underlying the `TCustomADODataSet`.  The exception occurs in the call to `Cursor.MoveNext`.

To do what you want, try constructing a calculated field in the SQL expression used to obtain the row data from the database.  Depending on the server you are using, you may need to use a TAdoQuery instead of a TAdoTable to get the rows.